# How can I get all values of a mysql table in JSON from a php script?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, json

This is php script that fetches a table values from mysql (one row). & echoes it as JSON

```
<?php  
      $username = "user";  
      $password = "********";  
      $hostname = "localhost";  
      $dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to 
      connect to MySQL");  
      $selected = mysql_select_db("spec",$dbh) or die("Could not select first_test");  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM user_spec";  
      $result=mysql_query($query);     
      $outArray = array(); 
      if ($result) { 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $outArray[] = $row; 
       } 
      echo json_encode($outArray);  
?>
```

this is HTML file to receive & print json data.
    
        
        
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
        
        //$('document').ready(function() {

```
    function Preload() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function(jsonData){  
    $.each(jsonData, function(i,j)
    { alert(j.options);});
    });} 

// });
    </script></head>

    <body onLoad="Preload()">
    </body>

</html> >
```

Comment: did you ask this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963057/how-to-return-data-fetched-from-mysql-into-a-php-file-as-json

Comment: no, code is same about which I ask other early things but now with some clarity & addition in code, I have new question that is ahead from previous ones. But if there is something special to care about it, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your PHP needs to actually put all the rows together:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_spec"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);    
$outArray = array();
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $outArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($outArray);
```

Your Javascript needs to look at each of the rows..

```
$.getJSON("/whatever.php", function(jsonData) { 
   for (var x = 0; x < jsonData.length; x++) {
      alert(jsonData[x].options);
   }
});
```

Comment: did u put for ech row in exact php syntax ?

Comment: @babar The `for each` is in the javascript code, not the PHP side.

Comment: r u sure javascript has for each loop ?

Comment: yes, & it gives no output. If I run php script, that output as     [{"options":"smart_exp"}] where options is name of column & smart_exp 1st row.

Comment: OK, its called a 'for in' loop in javascript & it has the syntax " for(var row in jsonData){alert(row.options);} " But it opens an alert saying 'undefined' with ur code, not value is ouputted in HTML while php outputs [{"options":"smart_exp"}], 'smart_exp' is 1st value in 'options' column.

Comment: @babar I realized an issue with the php code and corrected it... try again.  I will also add a different JS method.

Comment: actually this does what I was expecting as I have done this earlier, it raises error, '
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\conn_mysql.php on line 12'.

Comment: I think we can stick with "$result=mysql_query($query);  
      $data = array();  
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
      { $data = $row; }  
      echo json_encode($data);" as I have tested it in php by echoing before json convert & it returns all values from table. The problem is actually I think in getjson & most probably with 'for in' loop of js. If I output jsson in php it shows last vaöue of 'options', & if in HTML, I output like 'json.options', it also shows last value, but row.options ouputs 'undefined'.

Comment: @babar it has to be $data[] = $row, otherwise you're only getting the last row... you see why if it's just $data = $row, it's no longer an array, right?

Comment: $.getJSON with bew for loop is also not working, I tested it with while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) loop in php that outputs all mysql values as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @babar can you update your question with new code both php and js?.. I've also updated the php portion of my answer.

Comment: I have updated the code, php is now showing all result in json echo but html is still not showing outpu. I am still working on it, may be some misplaced brace etc.

Comment: @babar are the html page and the php page on the same address? change your getJSON call to href just conn_mysql.php without the full URL.

Comment: they are on same address & I change the address too but same result. I am thinking to use $.each method as often people who suffer from using for loop as ours recover using that method. U can have better understanding of it how to use.

Comment: OH OK Fosco, it starts working by using $.each() jquery method. As I said ealier many people who faced same problems as ours get solution with this method. Thanks a Lot Fosco for all ur help 4 getting me this far. I update my code. I should also thanX Cybrix whos post help me use this method correctly later. I will seek a lot of further help from u all guys with my this application & more. I

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) will only return a single row from the database. You will need a loop to retrieve all rows:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // add some or all of $row to the $data array
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: it happens same with ur solution too as with Fosco matter with little difference. The ouput of HTML is same i.e. the alert box ouput 'undefined'. While urs json echo in php output last 'options' value of the column while Fosco's json echo output the 1st 'options' value of the options column.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $username = "user"; 
    $password = "********"; 
    $hostname = "localhost"; 
    $dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect 
         to MySQL"); 
    $selected = mysql_select_db("spec",$dbh) or die("Could not select first_test"); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_spec"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $_ResultSet = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $_ResultSet[] = $row;
    }
       echo json_encode($_ResultSet); 
?>
```

and your jQuery would looks like :

```
$.getJSON("/yourscript.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, j) {
        // use: j.columnName
    });
});
```

Good luck

Comment: I can't comment Fosco's answer but your example wont work if the query returns more then one row. Only the first one will be returned to getJSON.